# Plotting a piecewise multivariable function

Tags: piecewise

I want to plot the following function :
\begin{equation} 
f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}, \; (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\ 0, \; (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}
\end{equation}
I tried the following :

```
 f[x_,y_]=Piecewise[{{x*y*(x^2-y^2), x!=0 or y!=0},{0, x=0 && y=0}}]
 Plot3D[f[x,y],{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}]
```

I keep getting a plot of $f(x,y)=0$ everywhere with an exception message. I don't know what is the code I need for the conditions, so if anyone could provide some help, it will be welcome.

Comment: 1) `Set::write: Tag And in 0&&y is Protected.` because you've used a single `=` instead of `==` and 2) what is `or` ? You mean `x!=0||y!=0` or equivalently `Or[x!=0,y!=0]` or use the special form `x!=0 ∨ y!=0`. Also make sure you clear x before running these fixes, because your mistake `x=0` will have assigned x the value 0 and it's no longer a symbol: This now works: `f[x_, y_]:= 
  Piecewise[{{x*y*(x^2 - y^2), x != 0 \[Or] y != 0}, {0, 
     x == 0 \[And] y == 0}}];
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`

Comment: Also you forgot to divide by `x^2 + y^2` in your code.

Comment: @flinty Thanks, it worked now and plotted a significant graph. However, the intersection of the plot and the x and y axis is blank, while normally it should be of value 0. Is there an explanation or a misinterpretation of mine?

Comment: Here's how the plot looks : https://ibb.co/CMr9rcg

Answer (score 4):

**Updated**

```
f[x_, y_] = 
  Piecewise[{{(x*y*(x^2 - y^2))/(x^2 + y^2), x^2 + y^2 != 0}, {0, 
     x^2 + y^2 == 0}}];
plot = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 > 0.015], 
   MeshStyle -> Gray];
Show[plot, Graphics3D[{Red, Ball[{0., 0., 0}, .1]}, Boxed -> False]]
```

[image]

**Original**

To highlight the removetable singular point {0,0,0},we can use the `Exclusions` and `ExclusionsStyle`.

**PS**

For `c` not equal to `0`, we have to use `Ball[{0., 0., c}` instead of `Ball[{0, 0, c}`,why?

```
c = Limit[(x*y*(x^2 - y^2))/(x^2 + y^2), {x, y} -> {0, 0}];
Plot3D[(x*y*(x^2 - y^2))/(x^2 + y^2), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 MeshStyle -> White, Exclusions -> {y^2 + x^2 == .01}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {{Red, Ball[{0., 0., c}, .1]}, {Thick, Green}}]
```

[image]